# PLivo hang_up and Sequential dialing

Tags: plivo

I am using plivo sequential dialing to round robin a phone call.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Response> 
    <Record maxLength="10800" action="http://example.com/recording-callback.php"     startOnDialAnswer="false" redirect="false" recordSession="true" /> 
    <Dial callerId="19515555555" timeout="15" action="http://example.com/action-webhook.php" callbackUrl="http://example.com/status-callback.php" callbackMethod="POST" > 
        <Number>14444444444</Number> 
    </Dial> 
    <Dial callerId="19515555555" timeout="15" action="http://example.com/action-webhook.php" callbackUrl="http://example.com/status-callback.php" callbackMethod="POST" > 
        <Number>15555555555</Number> 
    </Dial> 
    <Dial callerId="19515555555" timeout="15" action="http://example.com/action-webhook.php" callbackUrl="http://example.com/status-callback.php" callbackMethod="POST" > 
        <Number>16666666666</Number> 
    </Dial> 
</Response>
```

If the second user answers then terminates the call the call will continue to the end of the xml.  It will call the rest of the users even when I output hangup xml.  The call only terminates completely when the dialing party has hung up.  Does anyone have experience terminating a plivo phone call initiated with [sequential dialing](https://support.plivo.com/support/solutions/articles/17000050175-how-do-i-implement-sequential-dialing-)

Comment: same issue,find any solution ?